# How do I save text from website using beautifulsoup to .txt file?

Tags: python, text, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm new to python and web scraping. I've run into a problem and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

I am trying to copy the text from a website and when I print everything to the terminal, it pops out okay.

The issue is when I try to save it to a text file. I get this error:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "t3.py", line 43, in <module>
     Case_info.write(item.text+"\n")
     UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 16-17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm not sure how to fix it. My code for this particular section is below:

```
import mechanize
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
.
.
.

def main():
   b=mechanize.Browser()
   return b.open(mainlink+case)

html_text=main().read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)

g_data=soup.findAll("div",{"class":"Print"})

Case_info=open("case_info.txt", "w+")

for item in g_data:
  print item.text
  Case_info.write(item.text+"\n")

Case_info.close()
```

Also, What caused some of my confusion is this portion of code that did almost the exact same thing perfectly.

```
.
.
links = soup.findAll('a',href=True)
.
.
for link in links:
  if re.findall('keyword',link['href']):
   #print link.text, link['href'] 
   files.write(link['href']+"\n")
   names.write(link.text+"\n")
.
.
```

Hopefully someone can help clear things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) package, you can eliminate the error.

```
from unidecode import unidecode
for item in g_data:
  print item.text
  Case_info.write(unidecode (item.text+"\n"))
```